# Declare JavaScript variable as reference

Tags: javascript, reference, pass-by-reference, variable-declaration

I recall there being a feature of Javascript, such that the something resembling the following is possible:

```js
let foo = { bar: "bar" };
let { baz } = foo.bar;

baz = "baz";
console.log(foo.bar); // "baz"
```

Does such a feature exist? If so, what is the correct syntax to get this to work?

Comment: Is the result correct? In my side, the log prints "bar"

Comment: No, there's not. Or are you talking about the `with` statement? A `let` variable is never a reference to something else.

Comment: @Bergi No I do not think that is what I am talking about. I thought I remembered watching a video where someone wrote something similar to the example I provided, but maybe I am just imagining things.

Comment: Yes, you must be. The only cases where an identifier evaluates to a reference are global variables, `with` scopes, or module imports.

Comment: @Bergi is there any type of identifier declaration similar to `let { baz } = foo.bar`? It doesn't necessarily have to be a reference. The key part I remember is the curly brackets around the variable name.

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 `let { bar: baz } = foo` does the same as `let baz = foo.bar`. And then there's `import { baz } from 'some-module';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for destructuring assignment

```js
let foo = { bar: "baz" };
let { bar } = foo;

console.log(bar); // "baz"
```

Comment: While this technically doesn't answer my question about pass-by-reference this was exactly what I was thinking of and solved my problem.

Comment: im glad graham, you can rename the variable too: let{ bar: newBar } = foo; console.log(newBar);